# Unable to link UIViewController IBOutlets with StoryBoard

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, iboutlet

I have two UIViewControllers (A and B) in storyboard. The A view controller has a property

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController *viewController;
```

that I want to link via storyboard to B.

The outlet shows under the the IBOutlets section in storyboard menu but I'm unable to link.
It might seem strange why I'm trying to do that but I need it. Someone knows how to do that?

Comment: IBOutlets are usually weak and not retain.

Answer (score 6):

IBOutlets are connections within a single view controller. Create references to objects inside the view controller so you can use those objects in code.

You cannot create IBOutlets from one view controller to another one. A property is the correct way to go, but you have to assign the property in code. Normally when one view controller creates another one, it might set a reference to itself.

```
OtherViewController *otherViewController = [OtherViewController alloc] init];
otherViewController.masterViewController = self;
// at this point "otherViewController" has a reference to the current view controller
```

Comment: What if I have a parent view controller whose child I can determine at build time?

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand what I need to do. I need to create a [custom segue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomSegues/CreatingCustomSegues.html) to achieve the same result as when you link a UINavigationController to other ViewController and mark as RootViewController. It is done by segue and not by IBOutlet.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late to the party however I put together a segue class to help with this job. View the git repository to see the class in action: https://github.com/datinc/DATOutletSegue.

Basically it uses the identifier of the segue to connect to the parent controller